# Migrating Android App from SDK 33 to SDK 34( Android 13 to Android 14)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-14

#### Problem Description:

I'm currently working on migrating an Android app from SDK 33 to SDK 34 (Android 13 to Android 14).

During the migration process, I encountered warnings in the manifest files of my dependencies, specifically in the gradle cache files (from my dependencies) located at `.\..\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\`.

These are the warnings that are provided by the "Reverify" tool in the SDK Upgrading Assistant.

[image: That are warnings which i should review suggested by "Reverify" in SDK Upgrading Assistant]

> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\0432dc32f0599a70f4bec524d2c8c653\transformed\jetified-components-core-4.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:19:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ced70cb56e79f588eae8a97fd3363cf\transformed\work-runtime-2.9.0\AndroidManifest.xml:39:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ced70cb56e79f588eae8a97fd3363cf\transformed\work-runtime-2.9.0\AndroidManifest.xml:46:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ced70cb56e79f588eae8a97fd3363cf\transformed\work-runtime-2.9.0\AndroidManifest.xml:53:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\648522b8fbd9bd454aa2864be0ae4477\transformed\jetified-firebase-messaging-20.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml:28:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\83b6e9c751c3b95e4dba10814e63b104\transformed\room-runtime-2.6.1\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\863f78852b5da6ea3241a620d563db4c\transformed\jetified-play-services-measurement-17.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:35:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\863f78852b5da6ea3241a620d563db4c\transformed\jetified-play-services-measurement-17.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:39:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\997a7cd5ba2e549ccaf97bcb33d15f88\transformed\jetified-uisdk-full-1.13.2\AndroidManifest.xml:101:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\adaa6a5607bbe69c2669747f255470c9\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-17.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:8:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\e47e3510d32003366425f5309bfa1931\transformed\jetified-transport-backend-cct-2.3.1\AndroidManifest.xml:29:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\e7e998bd2888af2d32f2419483114c42\transformed\jetified-library-1.0.6\AndroidManifest.xml:12:9
>
> .....gradle\caches\transforms-3\f03ef7893eea414a67e9fe36ce6e46fc\transformed\jetified-transport-runtime-2.2.4\AndroidManifest.xml:26:9

#### Environment:

- Android Studio `Hedgehog`
- Gradle version: `8.0`
- Android Gradle Plugin version `8.1.4`
- Java `17`
- Kotlin:

  ```
   buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
      ext.kotlin_compose_version = '1.4.8'
      ext.nav_version = "2.5.2
  ```
- BuildTools:

  ```
   android {
      compileSdk 34
      buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
      defaultConfig {
         applicationId ""
         minSdkVersion 24
         targetSdk 34
  ```

#### Steps Taken:

1. Checked release notes for SDK 34 and dependencies.
2. Fixed all warnings from my Application Manifest. All of these 13 are from external libraries.
3. Updated dependencies to the latest versions, but the warnings persist.

I have read official documentation and some articles but I couldn't find a solution to this problem:

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance on how to resolve these manifest warnings during the SDK migration.
**Thank you gratefully in advance for your help !!**

Comment: `currently working on migrating an Android app from SDK 33 to SDK 34 ` Well i wonder why that should give work. And please dont post images. Post the text.

Comment: I know that it's early to do that but I need to integrate one SDK. In the process, It was required to use compileSDK and targetSDK as 34 :/ @blackapps

Comment: Please post the text the same way as visible in the image. Conserve the lines.

Comment: I edit it, can so look it now :)))

Comment: @RedCoder did you resolve thee issue?

Comment: No, @MostafaOnaizan I didn't succeed yet. Can you help please :)

Comment: @RedCoder yes, I did solve the issue and updated 3 apps and got approved on the play store. 1- update any gradle if it suggested to do so. 2 update all the deps to latest, update kotlin version. test the app on 34 sdk emu or physical. build it and send it to play store and it will be approved. the sdk assistance will still show you these warning. but dont wory about it. I think they may fix this in future android release. the only thing you should do is update your deps as mentioned before. good luck